# Change content in wordpress custom theme for cached page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, caching

I want to change banner for specific time and remove it when the time is up on wordpress custom theme page, but don't know what to do with ngnix caching in order to make that banner visible for all visiters.

I tried to create custom route(banner-automation) which will be called via js when is time to replace old banner with new one. That request with timestamp in it should bypass cache and load new banner through php (to be persistent, when page is reloaded). But that approach doesn't work...

Custom route: [image]

Php logic for displaying banners: [image]

Js
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: using javascript to bypass server cache is a good strategy; where you say `But that approach doesn't work`, can you explain why?

Comment: Don't know, maybe the script isn't even loaded because of cache. I'am new to this and don't in what order should i go.

Comment: One starting point would be for you to edit your question and include the code you tried so far.

Comment: Here it is, if need something else I'll post.

Comment: shouldn't the function name `custom_banner_automation` match the name passed for the callback argument, which is `custom_banner_route`?

Comment: My logic is to send request (via js) to "custom_banner_route" with new param to bypass cache, and after that server will reach to php and database because that url is not in cache, and when server reach to php "custom_banner_automation" will echo banner. That is logic, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I can't see `function custom_banner_route()` anywhere in your code

Comment: There it is now.

Comment: that means `custom_banner_automation` is never called.

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to mention that, it is called on front-page.php

Comment: When you invoke a rest api endpoint, wordpress will run the function specified in the `callback` argument of the route. Which is `custom_banner_route`. In there, you just `echo 'test';`. So the function `custom_banner_automation` is never executed. Is it possible that you want to use `custom_banner_automation` as your callback?

Comment: If I use "custom_banner_automation" as callback, how I will display banners on front-page.php?

Comment: in front-page.php you should print and empty div, something like `<div id="dynamicBanner"></div>` and then populate it via javascript. You fetch your rest api route endpoint, receive some output, and finally append the output to the empty div.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.